# Shouldn't fprintf fail on a closed file?

Tags: c, printf

Please observe the following terminal output:

```
$ cat fprintf-closed-file.c
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    FILE * ofile = fopen("/tmp/goo", "w");
    int success = fprintf(ofile, "Hello %s\n", "World!");
    printf("Success: %d\n", success);
    fclose(ofile);
    success = fprintf(ofile, "Trying again...");
    printf("Success: %d\n", success);
}
$ clang -o fprintf-closed-file fprintf-closed-file.c
$ ./fprintf-closed-file
Success: 13
Success: 15
$ cat /tmp/goo
Hello World!
```

Section 7.21.6.1 of the C11 standard says:

> The fprintf function writes output to the stream pointed to by stream,
>   under control of the string pointed to by format that specifies how
>   subsequent arguments are converted for output.

followed by the description of the conversion specifiers but ending with:

> Returns
>
> The fprintf function returns the number of characters
>   transmitted, or a negative value if an output or encoding error
>   occurred.

It would seem that given that the file is closed by the time of the second `fprintf` call, it should fail, but it doesn't. I tested this using Clang 4.0.1 and GCC 4.8.4 on Kubuntu Trusty 64 bit.

Is my understanding of the standard faulty, or should I go file a bug?

Comment: Undefined behavior is undefined.

Comment: well FILE IO use buffer so that doesn't surprise me. `fprintf()` just don't look if FILE is valid. Use `fflush()` to be sure that all is print. But whatever UB is UB.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quoting C99, **7.19.3 Files**:

> 4. [...] The value of a pointer to a `FILE` object is indeterminate after the associated file is closed (including the standard text streams).

Thus:

```
fclose(ofile);
success = fprintf(ofile, "Trying again...");
```

The second line reads from `ofile`, which (after `fclose`) has an indeterminate value. This has undefined behavior.

See also Annex J.2:

> 1. The behavior is undefined in the following circumstances:
>      [...]
>
>    - The value of an object with automatic storage duration is used while it is indeterminate (6.2.4, 6.7.8, 6.8).
>    - The value of a pointer to a FILE object is used after the associated file is closed (7.19.3).

Comment: You quote C 1999, but the question asks about C 2011. It seems this did not change, but you might want to clarify that it does cover the version the question asked about (both 1999 and 2011, and likely later).

Answer (score 4):

No, this is not a bug. What you are doing is undefined behaviour, as per `C11 Annex J.2`:

> The behavior is undefined in the following circumstances:
>
> ...
>
> - The value of a pointer to a `FILE` object is used after the associated file is closed (7.21.3)

Hence, an implementation is free to do whatever it wants in this case. As per the quote, section `7.21.3` provides more detail on this matter.

Comment: I wish I could accept both answers. Accepted the other one only because of the extra effort in quoting the additional section. Thanks to you too!